Flutter Error: “No podspec found for flutter_meta_sdk_flutter in .symlinks/plugins/flutter_meta_sdk_flutter/ios” when running Flutter project on iOS
I’m encountering an issue when running my Flutter project on iOS. The build fails with the error

[!] No podspec found for 'flutter_meta_sdk_flutter' in '.symlinks/plugins/flutter_meta_sdk_flutter/ios'.

The project works on android
I recently added the flutter_meta_sdk_flutter plugin to my Flutter project to integrate Facebook’s Meta SDK. Everything works fine on Android, but when I attempt to run the project on iOS, the build process fails with a podspec error related to the flutter_meta_sdk_flutter plugin.
Tried Solutions:
pod install --repo-update output:



Cleaned the Flutter project:


Ran flutter clean
Reinstalled dependencies using flutter pub get


Rebuilt iOS-specific code:


Deleted Podfile.lock and Pods/
Ran pod deintegrate
Reinstalled pods using pod install --repo-update


Verified the plugin: Checked the plugin’s documentation on pub.dev to ensure it supports iOS, but couldn’t find specific information related to iOS support.
Manually linked the plugin in the Podfile:


Added pod 'flutter_meta_sdk_flutter', :path => '.symlinks/plugins/flutter_meta_sdk_flutter/ios' to the Podfile.
Reinstalled pods, but the error persists.

Additional Information:

Flutter Version: 3.24.1
iOS Deployment Target: 17.5.1
Xcode Version: 15.4
Plugin Version: flutter_meta_sdk_flutter: ^1.0.5

pupspec.yaml:
name: app
description: "DESCRIPTION"

publish_to: 'none' 

version: 7.7.9+7036

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.4.0 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  app_tracking_transparency: ^2.0.6
  awesome_notifications: ^0.9.3+1
  badges: ^3.1.2
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  cached_network_image: ^3.4.0
  carousel_slider: ^5.0.0
  crypto: ^3.0.5
  device_info_plus: ^10.1.2
  dio: ^5.6.0
  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.5
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^5.1.4
  firebase_analytics: ^11.2.1
  flutter_checkout_payment:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/lucasuracosta/flutter_checkout_payment.git
      ref: master # branch name
  firebase_core: ^3.3.0
  flutter_credit_card: ^4.0.1
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^6.0.4
  #TODO remmber to check tabby version before updating this pacakge to newer versions
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.8.0  #downgraded because of tabby package constraints ^1.5.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^17.2.2
  firebase_messaging: ^15.0.4
  flutter_phoenix: ^1.1.1
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  flutter_secure_storage: ^9.2.2
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.15.1
  pay: ^2.0.0
  get: ^4.6.6
  get_storage: ^2.1.1
  google_sign_in: ^6.2.1
  http: ^1.2.2
  path_provider: ^2.1.4
  permission_handler: ^11.3.1
  persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2: ^5.3.0
  retry: ^3.1.2
  selection_menu: ^2.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.3.2
  shimmer: ^3.0.0
  sign_in_with_apple: ^6.1.1
  url_launcher: ^6.3.0
  webview_flutter: ^4.8.0
  icons_launcher: ^3.0.0-beta.3

  tabby_flutter_inapp_sdk: ^1.5.0
  phone_form_field: ^9.2.5
  sentry_flutter: ^8.7.0
  in_app_review: ^2.0.9
  is_first_run_plus: ^1.1.0
  jiffy: ^6.3.1


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0
  sentry_dart_plugin: ^2.1.0 

I’m unsure if this issue is due to the plugin not supporting iOS (which I doubt), an incorrect setup on my side, or something else.
How can I resolve this issue and successfully run my Flutter project on iOS?

I faced the same issue once with another package I think it was flutter_keyboard_visibility ,
I was migrating a legacy project to a new Flutter version,
to resolve this issue you should probably delete the Pods folder [not Podfile] and Podfile.lock from ios folder then rerun pod install
this worked for me at that time
checkout this issue on flutter GitHub's repository

I changed the package to this one flutter_meta_sdk, and it worked.
It seems there's a problem with flutter_meta_sdk_flutter
